# Why does user.id retain value even after committing delete?

Tags: sqlalchemy

So I added users:

```
john = User(name='John') 

mary = User(name='Mary')

session.add([john, mary])

session.commit()

mary = s.query(User).filter(User.name == 'Mary').one()

mary.id
```

output: 2

```
session.delete(mary)
session.commit()

mary.id
```

output:2

- Why does the 2 remain?

I am working on a tutorial from pythoncentral.io, if that helps

https://www.pythoncentral.io/understanding-python-sqlalchemy-session/

Comment: My guess is just caching. The object isn't in the database anymore, you're just talking about a value on the object that is still connected with `mary`.

Comment: do I need to redefine it to drop the value or is there someway to reset or drop the value of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object isn't in the database anymore, you're just calling a value on the object that is still connected with `mary`.

I can't think of any reason why you'd need to do anything special with it. You're done with the object, right? Ignore it. The value of `mary.id` is just an echo of its former presence in the database.

But if you want to keep using the `mary` object, perhaps recommitting it without the original id, you have to use `make_transient()`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import make_transient

make_transient(mary)
```

Now you can readd `mary` to the database and recommit her. She will retain her original id number, but you can easily prevent that by setting `mary.id = None` before you readd and recommit her.

Comment: Thanks, I guess if I were to really use 'mary' I'd probably redefine it so it doesn't matter.